# Mocking classes using JMockit

Tags: java, testing, jmockit

I'm new to Mocking frameworks. The framework which I'm now working on is JMockit.I have a doubt. Forgive me if my understandings on this topic is very poor.

I have a class A which extends an abstract class. The class is like this:

```
class A extends AbstractClass{
      private B b = UtilClass.getBean("b");
      private C c = UtilClass.getBean("c");

  .........
  .........
  .........

}
```

The UtilClass is like this:

```
public final class UtilClass{
  private static UtilContext context = new UtilContext();
   //getBean method which returns a bean object
}
```

i want to mock the getBean method. So to mock this method I have to mock the UtilContext class. If it is instantiating some other class, then i have to mock that too. This way i have to mock lots of classes, which is not a good idea.  Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to access the getBean method in the UtilClass, you can mock the whole UtilClass and disable its static initializations with the `$clinit` method (it will not disable the static initializations that are resolved at compile time (constants)):

```
new MockUp<UtilClass>() {
    @Mock
    void $clinit() {
        //disable static initialization
    }

    @Mock
    public static SomeType getBean(String s) {
        if("b".equals(s)) return new B();
        if("c".equals(s)) return new C();
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried this out. This is working. Thank you.

Comment: @SnehaParameswaran this is old, but please consider accepting the answer if it helped you resolve your problem.